# Mongoose and ExpressJS - modular architecture?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to have each file for each model - i.e. user and country.
Currently, I solved this the following way:

*person.js*

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('./mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    admin: Boolean,
    location: String,
    meta: {
        age: Number,
        website: String
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date,
    country: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Country'
    }
});

userSchema.methods.toString = function() {
    return `I am ${this.username} and I'm from ${this.country.name}`;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', userSchema);
```

*country.js*

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('./mongoose'),   
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var countrySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date,
    people: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Person'
    }]
});

var Country = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);

module.exports = Country;
```

So my question is as follows: how does the mongoose reference two tables? For example, in `Person` schema, I reference the country by providing `ref: 'Country'`, but I never included the model in the `Person.js` file. Am I doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

Taking the below answer into the consideration, I now have 3 files:

*database.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/people');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

module.exports = mongoose;
```

*person.js*

```
    /*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('./database'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    admin: Boolean,
    location: String,
    meta: {
        age: Number,
        website: String
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date,
    country: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Country'
    }
});

userSchema.methods.toString = function() {
    return `I am ${this.username} and I'm from ${this.country.name}`;
}

mongoose.model('Person', userSchema);
```

*country.js*

```
    /*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('./mongoose'),   
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var countrySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date,
    people: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Person'
    }]
});

mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);
```

Now when I include all these 3 files into a test file, e.g.:

```
var mongoose = require('./database'),
User = mongoose.model('Person'),
Country = mongoose.model('Country');
```

I get the following error: `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Person"`. I get the same error for `Country` if I delete the `User` variable. It appears as if mongoose is trying to define the model, not retrieve it. What seems to be the problem?

**UPDATE 2:**

OK, when I include now these documents, I do the following:

```
require('./person');
require('./country');

var User = require('mongoose').model('Person'),
Country = require('mongoose').model('Country');
```

Comment: Mongoose keeps a "registry" of all the models you register. For example a "later" call of `mongoose.model("Country") will retrieve the named model. So actually you don't need the `module.exports = Country` line and could just use the `mongoose.model("Country")` call to import the `Country` in another module that uses it. It's a "global" registry, just in the same way that `require('mongoose')` in another module does **not** create another "instance" of `mongoose`, but just re-uses the existing instance.

Comment: interesting notion. I've updated my code, I get an error with this approach.

Comment: You "still" need to require the modules where you actually "define" the models in the first place, and that is because the listings there "register" the models and attached schemas with mongoose. The only thing I told you is the `module.exports` is not required, since mongoose will recall the model "by name". Which is the point that actually answers your question. The models are "registered" with mongoose by "name", which of course is the argument to `ref`.

Comment: You're right, I haven't read your response carefully enough. I've added **UPDATE 2:** subsection to my question, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: More or less. I'd do it cleaner by just using ( in addition to the module requires for the model definitions ) `var mongoose = require('mongoose'), User = mongoose.model("Person");` So understand that once you did `mongoose.model('Person',personSchema)` then the subsequent call "retrieves" rather than "registers" since that initial call does the registration. And once registered as `'Person`' if you did `ref: 'person'` in lowercase, then that does not actually match the registered model name, and you would get an error, when you tried to do anything with that reference like with `.populate()`.

Comment: Got it, so the `model` and `ref` must have the exactly same string (when referencing tables, of course)? If you can re-write your response and answer the question here, I will accept your answer.

Comment: It sort of became one didn't it :) I'll see if I can translate that into something coherrent.